# How to search this kind of pattern in regex

Tags: python, regex, regular-language, qregularexpression

**This is the sample text I want to get the regex of the Match specified string that regex will qualify the Not match conditions**

> 1abc.def.ghi (Match)
>
> abc.111.ghi (Match)
>
> 123.123.123.132.123.123 (Match)
>
> 123.123.123.132.123.123.123.123.123.132.123.123.123.123.123.132.123.123(Match)
>
> 123.123.123.132.123.*12335* (Not Match)
>
> *7645*.123.111.887 (Not Match)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please post  a [mcve] example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck

Answer (score 0):

The task is defined by example.

Let's try to formalize it:

all valid matches contain only characters from the set [123abcdefghi.];

significance of 3 characters separated by dot is questionable because one valid example has 4 characters in a row. Let's assume we can have arbitrary number of characters separated by dots.

It is unclear if we can use any letter from the valid range in any group;
let's assume that all groups are equivalent

then, repeated group will be
[123abcdefghi\.]+

Add start and end anchors to match complete lines only:

r='^[123abcdefghi.]+$'

this is one of many possible understandings of this set of examples.